# Change background color in vue.js based on a class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

New to vue.js and am wondering if this is a possible outcome. I have 8 different options of a background color that I want to render based on the given class name. I can achieve this with css but was wondering if there is a dynamic way with vue to accomplish this. my ideal outcome would be just change the class name in the markup and it will then render that associated bg color.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header__container" :style="{ background: color }">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1 class="page-header__text">
            Page Header Lorem ipsUm
          </h1>
</div>
```

js:

```
export default {
   name: 'Header',
   data() {
   return {
   color: '#333'
    };
   }
 };
```

css:

```
bg-one{
background-color: #673AB7
}
bg-two{
background-color: #7293A0
}
bg-three{
background-color: #45B69C
}
```

Comment: if u want to apply any css class declarated just have to bind the `class` and not `style`, i mean `:class="color"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kyz19b7r/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   bgColour: 'blue',
    classes: [ 'blue', 'red', 'green'
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" :class="bgColour">
  <select v-model="bgColour">
    <option v-for="myClass in classes" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```